# Retrieve Joomla sql database without the Initial Sql Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, joomla

I'm a student who recently got a mini job to help a company restore its website. The main website in question works fine, but the subdomain throws an error:

> Database connection error (2): Could not connect to MySQL.
>   Database connection error (2): Could not connect to MySQL.

All website files and folders stay intact, but the database is missing. The company has recently found itself looking back at the website and wants me to put it back up.

My question:

If I don't have an exported database, is it possible to get the mysql database from the files/folders in the joomla directory?

-OR-

Is there a way to extract the site's content (text, categories, etc) from the files I have without the database?

I have been hooked with this and would appreciate a candid solution.

Comment: The answer to both of your questions is no.
Joomla stores its data in the database, not in the file system (as most of the CMS systems do as thats what a DB is for).
You could be lucky finding some data like images or other physical documents like manuals and stuff, but the article data, texts, categories etc. is stored in the db and is not found in any shape or form in the filesystem of joomla.

Comment: jeah, unfortunately theres no solution here, thats why a proper backup strategy is such an important thing.

Comment: If your site is hosted by a hosting company they may have a backup available.  Also one thing I would suggest is possibly going to your host panel and finding phpmyadmin or whatever data base manager they have and then go look to see if there is anything there.   It's hard to see a circumstance in which someone accidentally deletes a database so it could be that the host did something to cause it to be inaccessible.